# Querying a child of email id when email id is the key in Firebase, to check if the child exists or not

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database in Android where I have the root "USERS" and there are multiple users with the key as email id.

So the schema of database is something like this and the database uses email id as main key for each user:

```js
{
  "USERS":
    { "ABC@GMAIL,COM" : 
      { "USERNAME": "abc",
        "URL": "SOME_URL",...
      }
    }
    { "DEF@GMAIL,COM" :
      { "USERNAME": "dfe",
        "URL": "SOME_URL2",...
      }
    }
    .......
    .......
    .......
}
```

Now the email id serves as the main key for each user. Inside the email id is the username key which I want is to do a query on. I want to check if the username exists or not?
So the usual way to do this is to have a Database Reference- something like this-

```
DatabaseReference mDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/USERS/" +  ???? + "/USERNAME");
```

Then add a value event listener on the database reference. In the dataSnapshot check if it exists or not-

```
dataSnapshot.exists()
```

Now I don't know what to append after "USERS". Also I want the database query to search username to be as efficient as possible. What could be the possible way to iterate through the email ids and check if the child key of email-id exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the results using orderByChild() function

```
databasereference.orderByChild("USERNAME").equal("whatever")
```

in order to get full performance add .indexOn attribute in firebase database rules

```
rules{
    //other rules
    "USERS":{
        ".indexOn":["USERNAME"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah but before that, I need to iterate on parent of username which is the email-id. And I don't know how to because, email id is the key.

Comment: Why would you need to irritate? This query will return the results with required username only.

Comment: If there are no results that means username don't exists otherwise you will get a datasnapsot and can extract email id by datasnapsot.getKey()

Comment: Because when I orderByChild databasereference.orderByChild("USERNAME").equal("whatever"), I get the whole database where key becomes "USERS" and values will be the whole objects which have the Child "USERNAME".Thus orderByChild("USERNAME").equal("whatever") will never be true.

Comment: What the best order by child can give me is whole object. That I can get without doing doing orderByChild by just making a reference to my "USERS" as I already have a database schema such designed. But Anyway thanks